# How can I create a "catch-all" firewall in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, firewall

We have a Symfony firewall which is only valid for a certain host. When users make requests to pages guarded by this firewall, we are catching the request and doing the right approval/deny/ask for login step.

It looks like this, roughly (some bits removed) and allows our-domain.com and direct subdomains to be used by this firewall.

```
        main:
            pattern:   ^/.*
            form_login: ...
            anonymous: true
            host: '^((([^.])+\.)?our-domain\.com)$'
            guard: ...
```

However, we are finding that a (cheeky) person is occasionally hitting one of these URLs but for a different host, e.g. an IP address or a different domain. As the firewall does not match this host, we are getting the following exception:

> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

We are exploring different ways we could prevent requests on "not allowed" hosts, but we've as yet unable to find a suitable answer.

One option that seems right is a "deny all" or a "catch all else" type firewall - something where we can say "if you didn't match any of the other firewalls, then treat this as disallowed".

Is there a way to do this in Symfony?

Comment: i would make this configuration in the webserver-config but after all i dont quite understand the question because your firewall does what you want it to do, it denies all but that specific host

Comment: Yes, we're considering how to do it in our webserver config but as yet have not determined a way to do it. You're correct in that it is denying a user. However it is unfortunately doing so by throwing a 500 error which triggers our error monitoring systems.

Comment: you can customize what will happen on accessDenied, https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html  for webservers there are tons of tutorial how to have a default-host and specific vhosts with servernames serveralias

Comment: I think we misunderstand each other John. The exception is not an access denied exception. I can of course add a global handler that catches this specific exception and suppress it in our error handling. However, this seens a kludge to me. I'd prefer to discover the correct Symfony way to handle multiple hosts. Our web server hosts multiple hosts but only one can be logged in on. We wish to ensure that only one host can be logged in on and reject the others. I want to know if there is a way of configuring as such in Symfony.

Comment: , yes @msg - that's exactly what we should be doing. If you wish to turn that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute `bin/console debug:router` you'll get an output similar to this:

```
Name              Method   Scheme   Host   Path
----------------  -------  -------  -----  --------------------------------------------
homepage          ANY      ANY      ANY    /
contact           GET      ANY      ANY    /contact
```

As you can see, by default all URIs are accesible on all hosts reacheable by your webserver configuration.

If you want to restrict them to a given host(s) and return a 404, you can use the [`host` parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#sub-domain-routing) in the route configuration.

To avoid having to add the parameter to each `@Route` annotation, you can configure it globally via yaml:

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    host: '^((([^.])+\.)?our-domain\.com)$'
```